# Int -> Integer: type conversation misunderstanding

Tags: haskell

Here is my code for the calculating fibonacci numbers:

```
f' :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
f' mf 0 = 0
f' mf 1 = 1
f' mf n = mf(n - 2) + mf(n - 1)

f'_list :: [Int]
f'_list = map (f' faster_f') [0..]

faster_f' :: Int -> Int
faster_f' n = f'_list !! n
```

It works fine while 'n' is small.  To resolve the problem with big numbers I would like convert Int-type to Integer:

```
f' :: (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> Integer
f' mf 0 = 0
f' mf 1 = 1
f' mf n = mf(n - 2) + mf(n - 1)

f'_list :: [Integer]
f'_list = map (f' faster_f') [0..]

faster_f' :: Integer -> Integer
faster_f' n = f'_list !! n
```

With this code I get the error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Integer'
In the second argument of `(!!)', namely `n'
In the expression: f'_list !! n
In an equation for `faster_f'': faster_f' n = f'_list !! n
```

Well, I have understood correctly the index of element in the list can not be Integer-type.
OK:

```
f' :: (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> Integer
f' mf 0 = 0
f' mf 1 = 1
f' mf n = mf(n - 2) + mf(n - 1)

f'_list :: [Integer]
f'_list = map (f' faster_f') [0..]

faster_f' :: **Int** -> Integer
faster_f' n = f'_list !! n
```

But now I get the error:

> Couldn't match expected type `Integer' with actual type`Int'
>       Expected type: Integer -> Integer
>
> ```
>   Actual type: Int -> Integer
> In the first argument of `f'', namely `faster_f''
> In the first argument of `map', namely `(f' faster_f')'
> ```

Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Switching from `Int` to `Integer` would *not* make your code faster; in fact, I would expect it to get slower...

Comment: The question is not of speed, but type overflow.  faster_f' 100 - works incorrectly with Int type

Comment: Sorry, my mistake; I misread what you wrote :s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why?

Because `f'` expects an `Integer -> Integer` function, but you're sending it `faster_f'`, which is an `Int -> Integer` function.

> And how can I fix it?

Probably the easiest way is to use `genericIndex` (from `Data.List`) instead of `(!!)`.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is to make your arguments `Int` (as they are indexes of Fibonacci numbers, not the numbers themselve), and use `Integer` just for the output:

```
f' :: (Int -> Integer) -> Int -> Integer
f' mf 0 = 0
f' mf 1 = 1
f' mf n = mf(n - 2) + mf(n - 1)

f'_list :: [Integer]
f'_list = map (f' faster_f') [0..]

faster_f' :: Int -> Integer
faster_f' n = f'_list !! n
```

Of course now you can't address Fibonacci numbers with an index outside the `Int` range, but practically you'll run out of space and time much, much, much sooner.

By the way, if you need a list of fibs, the "usual" implementation is

```
fibs :: [Integer]
fibs = 0 : scanl (+) 1 fibs
```

If you need just certain values, there is a fast calculation method similar to fast exponentiation using these formulas:

```
f(2n) = (2*f(n-1) + f(n)) * f(n) 
f(2n-1) = f(n)² + f(n-1)²
```

Answer (score 2):

Integer is the infinite type of Int, (Int is only guaranteed to cover the range from `-2^29` to `2^29-1`, but in most implementations it's the full 32 or 64-bit type). That's why you get the first error. The second error you get because `(!!)` is a function that takes an list and an Int

```
(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
```

There are a lot of other (and maybe easier) ways to calculate the  Fibonacci numbers. Here is one example that returns a list of all  Fibonacci numbers to the specified. The first call is done by `fibCall`

```
fib :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
fib 0 _ _ l  = l
fib n a b l  = fib (n-1) b (a+b) (a:l)

fibCall :: Integer -> [Integer]
fibCall n = n 1 1 []
```

If you just want the n<sup>th</sup>  Fibonacci number, change `[Integer]` to `Integer` and `(a:l)` to `a`.